# Compare text in Excel, Access or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, text, compare

While editing two excel sheets, we have lost the reference.

Now we have one Excel sheet with Long Desc like *AC SERVO MOTOR MHMD082AIG (PANASONIC) (CNC-PLASMA SPARE PARTS)*

The another Excel sheet contains two descriptions, Desc 1 and Desc 2. We have made these two descriptions by splitting the first and second 30 characters of the the Long Desc. We did not do this with any programming, but manually. Because we have to get the following result

**Desc 1 :** *AC SERVO MOTOR MHMD082AIG*

**Desc 2 :** *PANASONIC (CNC-PLASMA SPARE PA*

Note that the split is meaningful and readable.

Now :-(, how can I rebuild the mapping. In above example, I understand if I use the word *MHMD082AIG* I can map the excel. If I do this manually, I have to spend few days :-(.

Any idea using Excel or Access or SQL Server is highly appreciated

Comment: So the mapping is a cell reference to be held in the workbook which holds  the long desc pointing to a row in another workbook which contains desc 1 and desc 2 where the concatenated value of desc1, desc2 = long desc?

Comment: Do not forget that you can use ADO and DAO with Excel and that will allow you to create a query with LIKE.